# Cassandra move data on another cluster

Tags: cassandra, nosql, devops, cassandra-3.0

i have a 3 node Cassandra cluster (3.11.0) and i want to move this cluster onto another location.
i have a 3 vm in my old cluster (Tashkent cluster)

```
192.168.1.11 -1 node
192.168.1.12 -2 node
192.168.1.13 -3 node
```

and i have new (empty) cluster

```
172.17.5.10 -1 node
172.17.5.11 -2 node
172.17.5.12 -3 node
```

and i want to move all the data from old cluster, to new and my steps is (old cluster have RF=3 for all keyspaces and have a NetworkTopologystrategy BTW)

```
1) add old nodes as seeds to new cluster
2) bootstrap new nodes
3) nodetool cleanup on old nodes
4) then run nodetool decommision on old nodes, one by one
5) nodetool removenode <oldnodeip>
```

so my plan is correct? should i do nodetool repair after ster 3?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing bootstrap/decomission, it's could be much faster to do following:

1. Add all new nodes as a new data center
2. Adjust replication factor to use 2nd data center
3. Run `nodetool rebuild` from every node of the new DC
4. Switch applications to new DC
5. Decomission the DC

Steps 1-3 are described in the [following documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html), step 5 is described [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html).

Another possibility is perform the [replacing nodes one by one](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsReplaceNode.html).

Main advantage in the both cases is that you're minimizing the data movements between the nodes.  Otherwise you'll move the data when adding nodes, and then move again when doing decomission or removenode

Answer (score 0):

Nodetool cleanup should be replaced by nodetool repair. Cleanup removes extra data from nodes and running it in older nodes will not be beneficial, while repair streams any missing data. Also, nodetool removenode will not be required after decommission.Both perform the same function but in different ways.

Comment: thank you! but in the official docs, i see this "After all new nodes are running, run nodetool cleanup on each of the previously existing nodes to remove the keys that no longer belong to those nodes. Wait for cleanup to complete on one node before running nodetool cleanup on the next node."